# Deploying node.js application to Heroku

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

Using the [dead simple tutorial on Heroku's website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs) and when I run `git push heroku master` I receive the following error:

```
       Using Node.js version: 0.4.7
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       npm ERR! Couldn't read dependencies.
       npm ERR! Failed to parse json
       npm ERR! Unexpected token }
       npm ERR! File: /tmp/build_17bicinzz6vv0/package.json
       npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
       npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
       npm ERR! JSON.parse 
       npm ERR! JSON.parse This is not a bug in npm.
       npm ERR! JSON.parse Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-c3iD/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-E95q/cli.js" "install" "--production"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_17bicinzz6vv0
       npm ERR! node -v v0.4.7
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
       npm ERR! file /tmp/build_17bicinzz6vv0/package.json
       npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_17bicinzz6vv0/npm-debug.log
       npm not ok
 !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.2.0"
  }
}
```

There's absolutely nothing wrong with my JSON, which I got from their tutorial, because when I run it locally, it works great. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Looks perfectly valid and validates for me - are you sure you've commited any changes to the file and pushed to git so that the correct file is being pushed to Heroku?

Comment: I committed and pushed all of my changes but it still wouldn't work. I simply started over with the same tutorial and everything worked. Don't know what I screwed up the first time but the second time it worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling this would have had the answer

```
 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_17bicinzz6vv0/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the whole content in package.json as provided by Heroku tutorial....
I also got the same error, it was removed by adding engines.

```
`{
    "name": "app-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "~2.5.8",
      "ejs": "~0.7.1",
      "socket.io": "~0.9.6"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x"
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

try a newer version of Node.js